# How can I implement a button on an Android app widget to open my (hybrid) app

Tags: android, kotlin, widget, deep-linking

I have an Ionic / Capacitor app. Now I would like to implement a widget from which I can open the main app with deeplinks (this is done for example with URL myApp://deeplink1).
I managed to do that on the iOS side with

```
Link(destination: URL(string: "myApp://deeplink1")!, label: {
            Text("Deep Link 1")})
```

Now on the Android side I created the widget (Kotlin) as described here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets and it is working fine.
Now I would like to implement a similar "deep link" as on the iOS side. I couldn't find a working example yes (for Kotlin).
Thanks for help!

I implemented widget like described here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets

I would like to implement a button which opens a specific app (URL).

In the meantime Chat-GPT gave me a **working example** (opening the browser on button click)!

```
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.widget.RemoteViews

class MyWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {

    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout)

            // Erstellen Sie einen Intent, um die App oder URL zu öffnen
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            intent.data = Uri.parse("https://www.example.com") // Ändern Sie die URL nach Ihren Wünschen

            // Erstellen Sie ein PendingIntent für den Button
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0)

            // Setzen Sie das PendingIntent auf den Button in Ihrem Widget-Layout
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_open_app_or_url, pendingIntent)

            // Aktualisieren Sie das Widget mit den geänderten RemoteViews
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
        }
    }
}
```

Just make sure:

- alter ...RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.XXX to your widget
- alter ...intent.data = Uri.parse("XXX") to your desired URL. for opening installed app for example: myApp://deeplink1
- alter ...views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.XXX, pendingIntent) to the ID of your button

I had also to add the flags at the end of the line

```
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```